# Блок-схема всего проекта(C# Unity)

Tags: c#, unity3d

Хотелось бы сократить время "вникания" в новый проект на 500+ классов. Есть ли какая то возможность в Unity, или просто в проекте Visual Studio, наглядно увидеть все взаимосвязи между скриптами, в виде блок - схемы или blueprint?

Comment: Enterprise Architect в помощь, если разберетесь как пользоваться))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В свое время задавался этим вопросом, есть несколько сравнительно удобных вариантов:

- [Visual Studio Class diagram(только в VS Enterprise Версия)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hyxd8c85.aspx)
- [Type Dependency Diagrams in ReSharper 9 и старше](https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2015/01/28/type-dependency-diagrams-resharper-9/)
- Генерировать свои диаграмы с помощью [Roslyn](https://github.com/jpollard-cs/Diagrams)

Последнее представляется самым гибким, но при этом трудозатратным.